# Excel 2007 Formula - Collapse cells and its data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm currently using excel 2010 and have some data I'm trying to transform so to speak and output the results into sheet 2. I'm not sure where to start and was hoping for some guidance.

The image below is only a sample set of data. The actual spreadsheet consists of 92 rows and 78 columns. The first three columns are name and address and the rest are very similar to what is shown in the image. Some cells have a value, a zero, or blank. The rows in red is what I would like to accomplish.

[image]

Comment: The easiest way to do this would use an Excel VBA macro.  Would that be acceptable, or is there a requirement that it be done using formulas?

Comment: @Phil - There are no requirements. I didn't know what would be the best approach to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using VBA.

It assumes that your existing sheet is named "Sheet1", and the new sheet exists and is named "Sheet2".

```
Option Explicit

Sub CollapseData()

  Dim RowNbr As Long
  Dim SrcColNbr As Long
  Dim DestColNbr As Long
  Dim MaxRowNbr As Long
  Dim PeriodNbr As Long
  Dim MaxPeriodNbr As Long
  Dim SrcSheetName As String
  Dim DestSheetName As String
  Dim SrcSheet As Worksheet
  Dim DestSheet As Worksheet

  SrcSheetName = "Sheet1"
  DestSheetName = "Sheet2"

  Set SrcSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SrcSheetName)
  Set DestSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(DestSheetName)

  ' Determine last row number in use
  MaxRowNbr = SrcSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

  ' Copy name, addr1, and addr2 headings
  For DestColNbr = 1 To 3
     Call CopyCell(SrcSheet.Cells(1, DestColNbr), DestSheet.Cells(1, DestColNbr))
  Next DestColNbr

  ' Determine number of period columns in use
  MaxPeriodNbr = SrcSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 3

  ' Generate date headings
  DestColNbr = 4
  For PeriodNbr = 1 To MaxPeriodNbr
     DestSheet.Cells(1, DestColNbr) = "date" & Format(PeriodNbr, "##0")
     DestSheet.Cells(1, DestColNbr + 1) = "amount" & Format(PeriodNbr, "##0")
     DestColNbr = DestColNbr + 2
  Next PeriodNbr

  ' Copy data from Sheet1 to Sheet2
  For RowNbr = 2 To MaxRowNbr
     ' Copy name and address
     For DestColNbr = 1 To 3
        Call CopyCell(SrcSheet.Cells(RowNbr, DestColNbr), DestSheet.Cells(RowNbr, DestColNbr))
     Next DestColNbr
     DestColNbr = 4
     For SrcColNbr = 4 To MaxPeriodNbr + 3
        If SrcSheet.Cells(RowNbr, SrcColNbr) <> 0 Then
           ' Copy date from Sheet1 to Sheet2
           Call CopyCell(SrcSheet.Cells(1, SrcColNbr), DestSheet.Cells(RowNbr, DestColNbr))
           ' Copy amount from Sheet1 to Sheet2
           Call CopyCell(SrcSheet.Cells(RowNbr, SrcColNbr), DestSheet.Cells(RowNbr, DestColNbr + 1))
           DestColNbr = DestColNbr + 2
        End If
     Next SrcColNbr
  Next RowNbr
End Sub

Private Sub CopyCell(FromCell As Range, ToCell As Range)
   FromCell.Copy
   ToCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
   ToCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End Sub
```

Comment: Results are exactly what I expected. I'm just spot checking to make sure, but everything looks really good. Thanks for the help. Will look into the VBA code and learn exactly what took place. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it for the example you have shown. It should be simple to replicate the formulas for the whole set of data you have.

To get the first date that has an amount greater than zero, i am doing an array multiplication of the `amounts array > 0` and the `dates array`. then i invert this array (`1/array`). `AGGREGATE` function gives you the largest value  after ignoring the erros(`#div0`). Inverting again gives you the first date that has an amount greater than 0.

for the next date, i include one more criteria by checking if the date array has date greater than the date previously calculated, thus giving me the next date.

The formula for amounts are basically `HLOOKUPs` for the date that was retrieved.

for date 1

```
=1/AGGREGATE(14,6,1/((D2:I2>0)*D1:I1),1)
```

for amount 1

```
=HLOOKUP(D6,$D$1:$I$2,2,FALSE)
```

for date 2

```
=1/AGGREGATE(14,6,1/(($D$2:$I$2>0)*($D$1:$I$1>D6)*$D$1:$I$1),1)
```

for amount 2

```
=HLOOKUP(F6,$D$1:$I$2,2,FALSE)
```

for date 3

```
=1/AGGREGATE(14,6,1/(($D$2:$I$2>0)*($D$1:$I$1>F6)*$D$1:$I$1),1)
```

for amount 3

```
=HLOOKUP(H6,$D$1:$I$2,2,FALSE)
```